# regex for a character range with double character

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to to get a range of all names that start with "A" and end with "Be".

It should be something like `/^[A-Be]/` but that's not working.

So it would pull:

- Adam
- Alan
- Bart
- ... everything in between until
- Ben

"Brian" would not be included in range as it is not starting with "Be"

Hope it makes sense.

Thanks for help.

Comment: It will be space separated?

Comment: Could you please show an example (or examples) of the input string and the expected output / matches? This is currently very difficult to understand

Comment: I am actually using regex in a MongoDB query.  I need to be able to use ranges. What if I want all names starting with A plus names starting with B plus all names starting with C up to Ch as in "Chan". But the range stops there.. "Cirilo" will not make it. as range stops at Ch. In other words all names that start with A and all the way to Ch. Hope this makes sense guys Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^(?:A|B[a-e])[a-z]*$/
```

That is, the non-capturing group in parentheses matches an A on its own or a B followed by exactly one of the letters a-e, then after that match any letters zero or more times.

Comment: Why a non-capturing group? You won't get the whole names

Comment: Almost there.. I am actually using regex in a MongoDB query and it looks like it worked as per my example.  However I need to be able to use ranges so this just brings A and B names.  What if I want all names starting with A plus names starting with B plus all names starting with C up to Ch as in "Chan".  But the range stops there.. "Cirilo" will not make it. as range stops at Ch. In other words all names that start with A and all the way to Ch. Hope this makes sense guys Thanks for the help.

Comment: OK.. modified your answer to this /^(?:A|B|C[a-h])[a-z]*$/  and it gives me the desired result.  All names starting with A B and C all the way to Ch and it stops there.  Perfect.  What if I want the range A to Or I don't want to do /^(?:A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O[a-r])[a-z]*$/  which works just fine.. I just want to be able to enter A-O[a-r] somehow. Thanks again!

Comment: @ManuelSchmidt - the non-capturing group is because we don't want to capture the first two letters by themselves. The regex as a whole will still match whole names.

Comment: @DemianS - `/^(?:[A-N]|O[a-r])[a-z]*$/`

Comment: Works like a charm!  I will still have to do some functions to get what letter comes before the chosen end etc.. of range but I guess a letter array will take care of that...  Thanks for your help! Much Appreciated

Comment: @nnnnnn So got everything working except this curve ball.  What if the start and end range have 2 letters... for example start with "Ci" and end with "Go".  My logic would have it as /^(?:C[i-z]|D-G[a-o])[a-z]*$/ but it is not working.

Comment: Maybe `/^(?:C[i-z]|[D-F]|G[a-o])[a-z]*$/` - Study that carefully and think about how it works (assuming it does) - remember that for the regexes I've been suggesting the part in parentheses is listing alternatives for the first one or two letters.

Comment: Works! I could have sworn I tried something like that but after it didn't work I assumed you could not have more then one pipe in the parentheses.  Thanks!